# Access denied error when using VirtualQueryEx

Tags: winapi, memory-management, process, virtual-memory, access-rights

So, I wrote a program which is able to successfully read memory from most of processes using `VirtualQueryEx`. However, I've come across a process for which this function fails. It's not a system process, just a game process. Without Debug privileges I couldn't even open the process's handle. With them I am able to get the process's handle but still get access denied for `VirtualQueryEx`.

I'm not sure but maybe the process is private? If that's the case, what should I do to successfully use `VirtualQueryEx` function?

I've also read somewhere that I might have to suspend whole process's threads before running `VirtualQueryEx`, but so far I didn't need that... And when I used function `Thread32First` to get the first thread it gave me an error: `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`...

I would be very grateful for any help in this matter!

Comment: Clearly the game programmers didn't want you to mess with the game.  Which is pretty normal, users that spoil multiplayer games with hacks are a common scourge.  Given that there are some odds that I'd be playing the same game you want to spoil, I'd say that this problem doesn't need to be solved.

Comment: All I'm doing is only for educational purposes. I don't intent to spoil games. My goal is to find out what tricks are used in order to learn how to protect my own games better

Comment: This is an interesting question, but... It would probably be a lot easier to answer if you included some additional details on the process you're unable to read. Heck, even just the name of the game might help.

Answer (score 2):

How are you opening the process handle? From [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The handle must have been opened with the **`PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`**
>   access right, which enables using the handle to read information from
>   the process object.

Another possibility is that the target process and your process are different bitness (32 vs 64). In that case you either need to use `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32` or something like `VirtualQueryEx64` [from wow64ext library](http://code.google.com/p/rewolf-wow64ext/wiki/ExportedFunctions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the time I made this thread I meant I use Windows 8 64 bit. Anyway, I'm opening the process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS so I guess that PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION is already there. The different bitness sounded like a good idea so I compiled my program on windows XP 32 bit. I run it but similarily couldn't achieve access to the process. On Windows XP I couldn't get the process handle even with debug privileges.