# Getting access to any process's memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, kernel, antivirus

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit. I know C++ and basics of assembly. If I were to write an anti-virus program, it should be able to access any process's memory, right? I have managed to write a program that is able to read most process's memory, using VirtualQueryEx and ReadProcessMemory. However, I've come across an application that doesn't let me use VirtualQueryEx. Even with debug privileges it fails with Access Denied error.

Is there anything I can do to enable myself the access to the process's memory using VirtualQueryEx? Or should I take other approach to access such hard accessible processes?

I've already done some research and wonder which approach should I follow:

1. I've come across an information that it's possible to read any memory in kernel mode without any restrictions. Is that true? But in kernel mode there is no functions such us VirtualQueryEx or ReadProcessMemory. I guess I need to implement them by myself? But I've seen opinions that such functions are very unstable and in the future I might get a BSOD or sth... Some say I shouldn't even use kernel mode for reading memory purposes. Could somebody give me an answer how it actually is with this kernel mode?
2. I heard that applications might hook some APIs so that it prevents other apps from using these functions. Might VirtualQueryEx be hooked in that process? and that's the reason I get access denied all the time? If that's the case how could I unhook this?
3. Anti-viruses are not likely to do this probably, but would simple DLL injection work? I mean, if I were able to inject dll to that process then inside my dll I would already be withing that process's virtual address space so reading its memory shouldn't be a problem then?
4. Another approach?

I would be really grateful for any tips and help in this matter!

Comment: Serious anti-virus software requires more than just access to a process's memory. This is a major undertaking. If you're doing this alone you have a vanishingly small chance of success.

Comment: As Mike W says, it's extremely complex. And yes, if you are trying to read another process's memory in kernel mode while that process's memory is being swapped in/out, you could get BSOD, or worse, cause memory corruption.

Comment: Does the "access denied" process run under the SYSTEM or other high-privilege account? If your app running non-elevated or in a lower-privilege account? That could account for why you can't access its memory.

Comment: I don't know its privileges but that's not a system process that I'm trying to access. And yes I run my program with admin rights. @MatsPetersson Would freezing whole process before reading its memory help? I heard there are undocumented APIs which can be used to freeze whole process

Comment: No, because it's not (necessarily) the process that dictates what memory is available and what isn't.

Comment: @MikeW May I ask what else does such software need?^^ Cause it seems like admin rights and debug privileges are still not enough to access some processes' memory

Comment: I see you followed the advice given to your [last attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769151/access-denied-error-when-using-virtualqueryex) to hack a game and come up with a better explanation. Last time you did this *"to protect your games better"*, now you're doing it to the save the world from viruses. I wonder what it's going to be next.

Comment: No matter how you're going to interpret that, it's all about security. If you're not interested in the topic or don't want to post anything useful, then don't post. Everybody who wants to know this subject better needs some practice... And maybe would you not misinterpret my last thread? Reading process's memory is not hacking a game

Comment: Well, true, the desired result is to - allegedly - improve the security of your game. And still, if someone suggested to me that the best way to learn how to secure their bank would be by robbing another bank I'd probably not be completely convinced.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it's possible, but it will be very tedious and error prone. It will not be as easy as VirtualQueryEx/RPM. I would actually just ensure my user-mode application has enough rights to do the API calls and not read the memory in the kernel. Also you can't easily load a self made driver on a 64-bit Windows. You either need to sign your driver (costs money) or find some security hole in Windows (or start your machine in an unsafe mode).
2. Yes, that's possible. One way to hook APIs globally would be to write a driver that redirects the API calls. Another way would be global or targeted dll injection to hook the API calls. The latter you can check with a debugger. If the kernel redirects the calls, you can only detect that by being in the kernel yourself.
3. I doubt that this would work, because you'd need *way more* process rights to inject a dll than to query/read some memory. If you want to read a specific known application you could try to get the target to load your dll by writing a wrapper for some dll it loads and replace the original.
4. Are you sure you need to read memory from this process? Is it any of the System Process, Idle Process, CSRSS that cannot be opened from user mode? Have you lowered your requested rights as much as possible? It think you only need PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION and PROCESS_VM_READ.